# Generate a list from linear combination in simpy

Tags: python, sympy

I am using sympy to do some calculations, but I need to manipulate results of multiplications using rules I have to define. Let us suppose I have

```
a, b, c, d = symbols('a b c d', commutative=False)
res = a*b + b*c + c*d
```

I was wondering how can I write a function which takes res and gives a list of this kind

```
[[a,b],[b,c],[c,d]]
```

since every time I try to perform operations like `list(res)` python throws the exception `Mul (Add) object is not iterable`. Thanks in advance

Comment: What would you expect from `a**2 *b + b**2 * a`?

Comment: `[[a,a,b],[b,b,a]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way:

```
[x.as_ordered_factors() for x in res.as_ordered_terms()]
```

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for since I hoped it could also decompose powers (e.g. a**2=a*a), but I saw that decomposing powers is a little bit tricky and there are workarounds like `evaluate=False` which don't fully convince me

Answer (score 1):

There is no function for this already but you can make one like this:

```
def factors(expr):
    result = []
    for term in Add.make_args(expr):
        flat_factors = []
        for factor in Mul.make_args(term):
            symbol, power = factor.as_base_exp()
            flat_factors += [symbol] * power
        result.append(flat_factors)
    return result
```

That gives:

```
In [74]: factors(a*b + b*c + c*d)
Out[74]: [[a, b], [b, c], [c, d]]

In [75]: factors(a**2*b + a*b**2)
Out[75]: [[a, b, b], [a, a, b]]
```

Answer (score 0):

No sure, but do you wanna do something like this?

```
res = 'a*b + b*c + c*d'
def list_func(res):
    list1 = res.split('+')
    return ([item.split('*') for item in list1])

print(list_func(res))
```